# Finding the nth occurrence of a character in a String using IndexOf()

Tags: java, string, substring, indexof, lastindexof

I have a question regarding `indexOf()`. I am trying to program an `EmailExtractor` (Yes, this is a homework but I am not looking for code) which extracts the entire email address from a sentence that is input by a user.

For example -
**User Input:  Mail us at abc@def.ghi.jk with your queries.**
The program will then display **abc@def.ghi.jk** from the above `String`. I understand `indexOf()` and `substring()` are required.

The idea I have now is to use `indexOf()` to locate the '@', and then search for the empty space just before the email address input by the user (nth).

My code is as follows:

```
System.out.println("This is an Email Address Extractor.\n");
System.out.print("Enter a line of text with email address: ");
String emailInput = scn.nextLine();
int spaceAt = emailInput.indexOf(" ");
for (int i = 1; i <= emailInput.indexOf("@"); i++){
    if (spaceAt < emailInput.indexOf("@")) {
        spaceAt = emailInput.indexOf(" ", spaceAt + 1);
    }
}
```

I understand and am aware of the problem in my code.

1) `"Mail us at abc@def.ghi.jk with your queries".indexOf(" ")` is 4, I am trying to get 10. However, the IF Condition I have input will cause it to skip to the next instance of indexOf() which is 25. (Because 10 < 14).

How do I go about avoiding this from happening?

Once again, I am not looking for purely the answer rather, I am trying to work around a solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it necessary to use `indexOf` method?

Comment: Why don't you split the String and then find which one has an `@` within ?

Comment: The simple solution is to use some other variable instead of `spaceAt` to hold the result of `emailInput.indexOf(" ",...)`, and make sure the result is less than the index of `@`.  Then assign `spaceAt` to that result *only* if it's less.  Otherwise, you can use `break` to get out of the `for` loop since you're done looking.  This is an example of "lookahead", i.e. you have to look at the next result to see if it's acceptable before you actually use it.  Also think about what will happen if there are no more spaces when you do your `indexOf`.

Comment: +1 for stating clearly it is an homework, that you don't want code, and for showing what you tried.

Comment: Not every word with @ is e-mail address. Why don't you use Regex?

Comment: @Rohit : Yes, as mentioned this is a homework. We were taught up till String Operations, therefore the best method for me would be indexOf() and substring(). Thanks!

Comment: @ajb: Thank you so much for the input! I will work along those lines. I have tried working with break; but with your explanations, I understand it much better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about finding the space before and after the @

```
int at = emailInput.indexOf('@');
int start = emailInput.lastIndexOf(' ', at) + 1;
int end = emailInput.indexOf(' ', at);
if (end == -1) end = emailInput.length();
String email = emailInput.substring(start, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expressions instead of using `indexOf()` and `substring()`

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"+"[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"
```

use the Pattern and Matcher to validate the email id in your string.
[**This**](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/regex/matcher/validate-email-address-with-java-regular-expression-example/) may give you a clear view on it

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you could do is call `indexOf` and test the result in the same iteration of the loop, instead of saving the check for the next iteration. Something like this in mostly pseudocode:

```
spaceAt := 0
indexOfAtSign := emailInput.indexOf('@');
while (spaceAt < indexOfAtSign) { // you never really used i anyway
    temp := index of next space
    if (temp > indexOfAtSign) break;
    else spaceAt = temp;
}
```

(There'd need to be a small bit of corner-case testing, but only for if there are no spaces either before the @ sign or after the @ sign)

Comment: also if there are no spaces after the @ sign.